# Loading problem in Gmail, it quits in middle

Tags: dual-boot

I am using Ubuntu 15.04 now, but have had this problem since 14.04. I am dual booting with Windows 10.  My problem is when I go to Gmail, for example, sometimes it will quit loading and do nothing.  The same happens on Yahoo.  Windows does not have the problem so it seems the computer is OK.  Is there something wrong in my Ubuntu setup? I have never had this kind of problem with Ubuntu before.

Comment: Can you please give a few more details? What does "quits loading" mean? Does the web page not load fully or do emails not sync? What browser are you using?

Comment: I have tried Firefox and Chromium and Chrome.  Quit loading means when it is trying to load a page it will say Can't load page and check your internet connection.  In Gmail when I go to it it stops the loading indicator and then quits before it ever gets done.  I use Chrome for the Windows Browser. Thanks for any help Zacharee1

Comment: And this _only_ happens on email-related sites? It kind of sounds like some firewall is blocking email. Run `sudo ufw disable` in a terminal, reboot and try aagin.

Comment: This happens on gmail, yahoo news, some sites after loading the first page correctly it won't load a second page.  This is a problem that is very basic to the ability to download files?  In yahoo news it sometimes leaves out all of the pictures like it knows it can't load the whole thing.  The big problem with all the theories is that Win 10 works great with all the functions!  I am about to try to reinstall without saving data and see if that helps.  This is a very challenging problem!  Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's more of a Web browser problem. Which browser are you using on Windows and on Ubuntu?

If you're using add-ons on Firefox or chrome try disabling them one by one to see which one might be causing the issue. Try again with a different browser if it's not better.

Lastly you can try and change the default DNS of your system. Go to:
"Settings > Network" click to edit your network card. Under IPV4, uncheck automatic DNS and try using google's public DNS instead.

8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4

Comment: This should be a comment..if you don't have the permission to comment yet please wait till you get that privilege..

Comment: I'm so sorry for trying to help when no one had posted anything to help this guy...

Comment: I have tried Firefox and Chromium and Chrome.  All have the same results.  I haven't tried the DNS change yet, but I will later and let you know.  There has to be something basically wrong to stop loading a page like it does!  Thanks for help.

Comment: @itSp4x it's AskUbuntu policy that questions and suggestions should be put as comments. If you don't have enough reputation, then you have to post real answers. An actual answer includes a solution that is likely to work, not "it seems" or "it appears that".

Comment: This problem happens in gmail, yahoo news, facebook, etc.  I think it is sites that have a lot of data to load.  I have tried reloading the os without losing my information but do you think I should try to load os after formating? I don't want to lose Win 10 though.